# Gregorian Calendar 12 hour 24 hour confusion

Tags: java, mysql

I am using GregorianCalendar for getting time value.

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis() + " " + cal);
    }
}
```

When I use the cal.getTimeInMillis() in an mysql query, it interprets the time as 12 noon. Is my understanding correct? Or how to set it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you have to set hour as 0 for midnight and 12 is for noon.

Try Below code

```
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
```

Or Second way is

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
```

Comment: Found in the documentation that possible values for Calendar.HOUR are 0 - 11

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `HOUR` and `AM_PM` sets the hour in a 12-hour clock. So, e.g., your usecase:

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
```

Sets the hour to noon. Alternatively, you could have used `HOUR_OF_DAY` to use a 24-hour clock:

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
```

Comment: Except that "12 AM" should be midnight.